# How to suppress error message "ls no match"?

Tags: csh

Suppress ls: no match when pipe with wc.

```
%ls /tmp/kinhwa/*a*
/tmp/kinhwa/aa  /tmp/kinhwa/ab  /tmp/kinhwa/ca
%ls /tmp/kinhwa/*a* | wc
  3       3      45
%ls /tmp/kinhwa/*d* | wc  
ls: No match.
  0       0       0`
```

How to suppress `ls: no match.` while maintain word count as showed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using ls, can use find.

```
pglc00524> ls /tmp/kinhwa  
aa  ab  ca 
pglc00524 ls /tmp/kinhwa/*d* | wc 
ls: No match.
          0       0       0  
pglc00524> find /tmp/kinhwa/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*d*' | wc
          0       0       0  
pglc00524> find /tmp/kinhwa/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*a*' | wc
          4       4      58
```

Comment: Haha. I get `find: No match.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `csh`, you can suppress the "no match" output from command such as `ls` and `find` with,

```
set nonomatch=1
```